# Discrepancy between log-likelihood returned by logLik for normal linear models and "standard" manual calculation

Tags: r, lm

The log-likelihood returned by the `lm` method for the `logLik` function does not seem to match that calculated by hand.

To demonstrate, below I fit a standard linear model with only an intercept to a simple dataset with three points. I then extract the log-likelihood using `logLik` and calculate it manually by summing the logs of the pdfs evaluated at the mle.

```
test_df <- data.frame(y = c(0, 2, 4))
mod_lm <- lm(y ~ 1, data = test_df)
ll_logLik <- logLik(mod_lm)
ll_manual <- sum(log(purrr::map_dbl(test_df$y, function(x) dnorm(x, 
                                                   mean = mod_lm$coefficients[1], 
                                                   sd = summary(mod_lm)$sigma))))
c("logLik" = ll_logLik, "manual" = ll_manual)
```

As can be seen above, the generic `logLik` returns -5.836 whereas the manual calculation returns -5.728.

Digging into the method called by `logLik` (`stats:::logLik.lm`), the key lines to calculate the log-likelihood can be written as

```
n <- nrow(test_df); resid_vec <- mod_lm$residuals
-n/2  * (log(2 * pi) + 1 - log(n) + log(sum(resid_vec^2)))
```

which gives -5.728 as before.

However, according to the formula I'd expect for the log-likelihood below,

```
sigma <- summary(mod_lm)$sigma
-n/2 * log(2 * pi) - n * log(sigma) - 1/2/sigma^2 * sum(resid_vec^2)
```

I get -5.826 as calculated manually before.

If you fit a model to many more datapoints, say 1e4, then the results returned by the manual calculation, my formula and `logLik` are the same up until 7 significant places (not sure thereafter). For example:

```
set.seed(4)
test_df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(1e4))
mod_lm <- lm(y ~ 1, data = test_df)
ll_logLik <- logLik(mod_lm)
ll_manual <- sum(log(purrr::map_dbl(test_df$y, function(x) dnorm(x, 
                                                   mean = mod_lm$coefficients[1], 
                                                   sd = summary(mod_lm)$sigma))))
c("logLik" = ll_logLik, "manual" = ll_manual)
```

Both yield -14155.41.

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`logLik` evaluates the log-likelihood at the maximum-likelihood estimates of the parameters. The maximum-likelihood estimates of the coefficients are the same as the least-squares estimates, but the denominator of the maximum-likelihood estimate of the variance is `n`, while `summary(mod_lm)$sigma` is the squared-root of the unbiased estimate of the variance, whose denominator is the degrees of freedom, here `n-1`. So you get the same results if you do:

```
sd = sqrt(2/3)* summary(mod_lm)$sigma
```